# AtomicInteger: keep non-negative

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

Is there a way to perform a "decrement if result is positive or zero" operation with an `AtomicInteger`?
To clarify the desired behavior:

- if the current value is greater than zero, decrement
- if the current value is equal to zero, do nothing
- (negative current value is not handled)

Comment: I don't see a way.  Perhaps you could use `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`?  It's guaranteed to be always positive, and you can decrement it with `acquire()` or `tryAcquire()`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Java 8, [yes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#updateAndGet-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-):

```
atomicInteger.updateAndGet(i -> i > 0 ? i - 1 : i);
```

Before Java 8, [no](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: I am convinced that https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544968/139985 is a valid solution for prior to Java 8.  (And I think that is roughly what `updateAndGet` is doing ...)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could do something like this pre-Java 8:

```
int val = atomicInt.get();
boolean success = false;
while(val > 0 && !success) {
    success = atomicInt.compareAndSet(val, val - 1);
    if(!success) {
        // Try again if the value is still > 0
        val = atomicInt.get();
    }
}
// Check 'success' to see if it worked
```

Not the most elegant code, but I think it does the trick.

---

Informal proof of correctness (by @Stephen C)

In the case where there is no other thread modifying the `AtomicInteger`, `success` will be set to `true` on the first `compareAndSet` call.  So the code will be equivalent to

```
int val = atomicInt.get();
if (val > 0) {
    atomicInt.compareAndSet(val, val - 1);
}
```

which is clearly correct.

In the case where some other thread modifies the `AtomicInteger`, between the `get` and the `compareAndSet` then the latter call will fail because the *current* value is no longer equal to `val`.  So what happens then is that we call `atomicInt.get()` again to get the updated value ... and repeat.  We keep repeating until either we succeeded in the `compareAndSet` OR the current `val` is less zero or less.

The net effect is that *this thread* EITHER decrements the `AtomicInteger` once, OR it gives up because it sees that the value is zero.

Note the following caveats:

1. The retry loop may result in another thread "overtaking" and getting its decrement in before our thread.  (Another way of saying that is to say the algorithm is not "fair".)
2. If you immediately observed the value of the `AtomicInteger` after this sequence, you may observe that its value has changed ... again.
3. It is theoretically possible for the code to loop indefinitely.  But that requires other threads to be continually updating the `AtomicInteger`.

However, none of these caveats is a violation of the (assumed) requirements.

Comment: dont you think for this to work the method will need synchronized access?

Comment: It actually does work.  Proof added.  (If my proof is incorrect, please point out the errors.)

Answer (score -1):

Credit goes to @JB Nizet.

To know update is successful or not:

```
    AtomicBoolean isUpdateSuccessful = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    atomicInteger.updateAndGet( i -> {
        if( i > 0 ) {

            isUpdateSuccessful.getAndSet(true);
            return i - 1;
        } else {

            isUpdateSuccessful.getAndSet(false);
            return i;
        }
    });
```